# Use Pentaho Variable to Dynamically name EXCEL file

Tags: variables, pentaho

I am trying to dynamically name an excel file after processing it for archiving purposes.
If I process Logistics.xlsx I want to save it as U:\Archive\${varDP}.xlsx

Resulting file name U:\Archive\20190709.xlsx

I have tried Get system variable to get the date, This works fine. I have created the field (DateProcessed). However, I am unable to Set variables varDP to DateProcessed.

Thank you

Comment: Make sure to show the community what you've tried. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for assistance.

Comment: Are you having issues with the Set Variables step? I'm not sure I'm understanding what your specific problem is. You should have the Get System Info step hopped to the Set Variables step, then you just select the date field in Set Variables and give it a name. If the issue is that the variable is getting picked up in the excel output step, you may need to create two transformations for this to work properly. Variables that are created in a transformation cannot be used in that same transformation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set and use a variable in the same transformation. If you want to use a variable you should have a job with two transformations: first transformation gets the date and sets the variable; second transformation can then use the variable.

The main reason for that is that all steps initialise at the same time. Therefore, when the variable is read by the step that is using it, it's probably not set yet.

Answer (score 0):

For these cases of Variables usage and passing parameters, i've been forwarding [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56440614/pentaho-spoon-pid-how-to-move-files-to-folders-with-different-name-everytime/56445449?noredirect=1#comment99828062_56445449), it has a link to another answer of mine where i go step by step of how to pass parameters to another Transformation without 'Set Variables', and in the linked answerm i have sent a downloadable example.